# Podman rootless cannot mount NFS inside container

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, podman

I'm trying to mount NFS inside Podman rootless container. I tried several method with/without CAPS and security profile parameters. Unfortunately, mount works only, if Podman is run as root.
I'm spent 2 week on this issue, but honestly i'm out of ideas how to deal with this issue.

1. As root with cap-add container (Working)

> ```
> [root@rack-host1~]# podman  run --cap-add=CAP_SYS_ADMIN -it myredhatimage:8 bash 
> [root@d8e09797b797 /]# mount -vv -t nfs4 -o rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.12
> ```
>
> nfs-server06:/MoviesShare /data
> mount: nfs-server06:/MoviesShare mounted on /data.
> [root@d8e09797b797 /]# ls /data configs
> containers  movies  logs  pictures

2. As non root without caps [Failed]

> ```
> [podman-user@rack-host1~]$ podman  run -it myredhatimage:8 bash [root@fbd0cfca851d /]# mkdir -p /data  [root@fbd0cfca851d /]# mount
> -vv -t nfs4 -o rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.12
> ```
>
> nfs-server06:/MoviesShare /data  mount: /data: permission denied.

3. As non root with caps [Failed]

> ```
> [podman-user@rack-host1~]$ podman  run --cap-add=CAP_SYS_ADMIN -it myredhatimage:8 bash
> [root@56e79e6f30cf /]# mkdir -p /data
> [root@56e79e6f30cf /]# mount -vv -t nfs4 -o rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.12
> ```
>
> nfs-server06:/MoviesShare /data
> mount: /data: permission denied.

4. As non root with caps and privileged [Failed]

> ```
> [podman-user@rack-host1~]$ podman  run --privileged --cap-add=CAP_SYS_ADMIN -it myredhatimage:8 bash
> [root@bc40b4065cf1 /]# mkdir -p /data
> [root@bc40b4065cf1 /]# mount -vv -t nfs4 -o rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.12
> ```
>
> nfs-server06:/MoviesShare /data
> mount: /data: permission denied.

I use newest Podman 5.0.0-dev-d08414686 and RHEL8.9 with kernel 4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64

```
Client:       Podman 
Engine Version:      5.0.0-dev-d08414686 
API Version:  5.0.0-dev-d08414686 
Go Version:   go1.20.10 
Built:        Mon Jan 22 16:32:20 2024 
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Podman is configured to use runc engine. NFS is in version 4. Please let know.